# Calling attributes in belongs_to in the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure the best way to phrase this.

I have a database of buildings with a relationship (has_many) to units.

On my index page, I want to be able to call the price associated with the unit (associated with the building)

Ideally it would be something like

```
<%= buildings.each do |building| %>
<%= link_to building.name, :building %>
Unit 1: <%= building.unit.find_by_id(1).price %>
```

but that doesn't seem to work at all. Any ideas? I'm trying to call the first unit that belongs to the building, and then pull the price from that unit. And how do I declared the units in the index controller? Right now I only have @buildings in there.

EDIT: updated code.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `|build|` a typo? Should be `|building|`

Comment: My bad, yeah. (Not the source of the problem though)

Comment: Does `building.units.first.price` get you what you want?

Comment: Great, I just put it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
Unit 1: <%= building.unit.find_by_id(1).price %>
```

Into this:

```
Unit 1: <%= building.unit.first.price %>
```

Comment: Wait I have encountered a problem. It worked for a second but stopped. It says that price is an undefined method if I use .units, but if I use .unit is says .unit is an undefined method.

Comment: Sorry yes that should be `building.units.first.price` - unit is wrong. Odd that it was working and now it isn't it's not a typo somewhere is it? price is definitely a field on Unit?

Comment: It definitely is, I get "undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Should I add anything to my buildings index controller?

Comment: This: `"undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass"` suggests the building has no units (since `first` is returning `nil`). You could check before displaying the price, so: `building.unit.first.price if building.unit.first`